# How do I change a string at position

Tags: c#, chars

I'm aimed at speed, must be ultra fast.

```
        string s = something;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            if (s[j] == 'ь')
                if(s.Length>(j+1))
                    if(s[j+1] != 'о')
                        s[j] = 'ъ';
```

It gives me an error Error "Property or indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

How do I do it the fastest way?

Comment: Can you explain this process? What is your end goal?

Comment: what possible reason could you have to do this? just curious.

Comment: Looks like you've forgotten } at the end. I think the main idea is to auto-correct Russian words, because there are some weired rules about `ъ` & `ь` symbols :)

Comment: OCR often doesn't differ 'ъ' with 'ь' and that's fine. There's a rule in Russian that states "ь" only before "о". This should fix it, but it must be very fast.

Comment: The simple answer? You simply **can't** modify strings. If you need to, then whoever gives you the string must give it to you in a mutable format... if they don't, then there's no proper workaround for you.

Comment: @John Black: Your code seems to be trying to change ь to ъ if it's *not* before an о. Isn't that the opposite of what you want?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two options:

- Use a StringBuilder and keep track of the previous character.
- You could just use a regular expression `"ь(?!о)"` or a simple string replacement of `"ьо"` depending on what your needs are (your question seems self-contradictory).

I tested the performance of a StringBuilder approach versus regular expressions and there is very little difference - at most a factor of 2:

```
Method              Iterations per second
StringBuilder                  153480.094
Regex (uncompiled)              90021.978
Regex (compiled)               136355.787
string.Replace                1427605.174
```

If performance is critical for you I would *strongly* recommend making some performance measurements before jumping to conclusions about what the fastest approach is.

Comment: Regular expressions are very good, but I don't know if it's fast enough. Can you tell?

Comment: @John Black: Yes I timed it, and I think its probably fast enough. Perhaps you should time it for your specific data though.

Answer (score 3):

Fast way? Use a `StringBuilder`.

Fastest way? Always pass around a `char*` and a `length` instead of a `string` so you can modify the buffer in-place, but make sure you don't ever modify any `string` object.

Comment: something tells me this might be a joke, is it?

Comment: ... no, it's not. What makes you think it's a joke?

Comment: what about string.toCharArray and then modifying that?

Comment: It's neither the preferred way (like `StringBuilder`) nor the fastest way (like `char*`); it's just another potential method with neither advantages nor disadvantages. Any reason you think `char[]` has any advantages to `StringBuilder` or `char*`?

Comment: @Lambert - not really - just wondering.  It might work for his algorithm, but I imagine your use of StringBuilder would call replace at the appropriate time?  Agreed char* would always be the fastest but wondered if CharArray would be something that was a good compromise for anybody looking at C# code and crying at the site of a pointer.

Comment: @SB: `char[]` is totally fine, but it doesn't have any particularly special features (ease or power) so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in .Net is read-only. You could use `StringBuilder`.